# ASP.NET CORE MVC post form with FormCollection Model in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
<div>
<form id="frm_Index" asp-controller="Index" asp-action="SaveIndexData"
                          data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
                          data-ajax-failure="OnFailure" data-ajax-success="OnSaveSuccess_prop"
                          data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">

   // controls inside
 <button id="btnSave" onclick=" CheckForm(event)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

When i Click btnSave button it not posted to controller. 500 internal server error.
SaveIndexData(FormCollection collection) is not working

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveIndexData(FormCollection collection)
{
// json result
string result = "";
     // logic code

     return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: @Requib When you click your ```save``` button, did you see it hit breakpoints in the controller? and please post your AJAX code.

Comment: Can you show the code of `CheckForm(event)`?Your form will call it when you click the button rather than post the form.

Answer (score 1):

Changed from FormCollection to IFormCollection and it works with ajax call for btnsave with javascript function CheckForm(event) ajax call

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<JsonResult> SaveIndexData(IFormCollection collection)
    {
    // json result
    string result = "";
         // logic code
    
         return Json(result);
    }
```